# update cell data with results from procedure

Tags: sql, dbeaver, heidisql

i would like to run a procedure on a schedule, take the results from that procedure and input that data into a cell.

```
BEGIN 
    select location from StartPositions where id = (FLOOR(1 + RAND() * (5 - 0 +1)));
    UPDATE wanderingtrader.npcs
    SET startpos=''
    WHERE id=1;
END
```

when SET startpos =

i need this data to be the result of the location given by the id which gets the coords

Answer (score 0):

```
set startpos = (select location from StartPositions where id = (FLOOR(1 + RAND() * (5 - 0 +1))))
```

Comment: Can you improve your answer? For example by providing the procedure as an example and show how to use it?